# How to add "_routing.path" without downtime & reindexing in Elastic 1.x?

Tags: elasticsearch

Elastic 1.x allows to define in mapping default `path` for extracting required `routing` field, e.g.:

```
{
    "comment" : {
        "_routing" : {
            "required" : true,
            "path" : "blog.post_id"
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible to **add** that field on the fly, without a downtime?

So the mapping was previously defined as:

```
{
    "comment" : {
        "_routing" : {
            "required" : true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to reindex the documents, as well. If that path changes and the values are different this means that documents could have ended up in a different shard than in which they are now.

Comment: @AndreiStefan thanks for answer, actually what I am trying to do, is **adding** that path. I've edited the question to be more clear. Is **adding** possible from what you know?

Comment: No. It won't work. I just tested it. Even if the command is acknowledged the update is not applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update will not work. Even if the command is acknowledged, the update will not be applied.

You need to reindex the documents, as well. If that path changes and the values are different this means that documents could have ended up in a different shard than in which they are now. So, assuming that the change would have been possible, you are basically changing the hash that the documents can be **routed** and also **GET**ed (gotten) from shards and it will be a mess.